# Error when saving the canvas element using Html2canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html2canvas

I am trying to create a screenshot on a click and save the image in the pc. For this I am using the html2canvas plugin. 
here is my code

```
<body id="add" style="background-color: white">       
    <label id="contact" style="float: right; cursor: pointer;">Save Me</label>
    <h4>My Name Is <b>SUBHAJYOTI</b> <span style="color:red">MITRA</span></h4>        
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('#contact').on('click', function() {
                html2canvas($("#add"), {
                    onrendered: function(canvas) {
                        var link = document.createElement('a');
                        link.download = "ScreenShot.jpeg";
                        link.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg").replace("image/jpeg", "image/octet-stream");
                        link.click();
                    }
                })
            });
        });          
    </script>
</body>
```

Its working nice when click on "Save me" and the save the image. but the background of the image became black.[image]
Like the above picture. please any one help me.

Answer (score 0):

Yup I solve the problem. I dont know why but the problem is with jpeg. If I change the extension jpeg with png, then the problem is solved.

```
link.download = "ScreenShot.png";
link.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
```

Comment: because there is no alpha channel in jpeg image format and that the canvas' default transparent pixel is set to `rgba(0,0,0,0)` *(even if you do set explicitely to another transparent value like `rgba(0,255,0,0)`)* which when you remove the alpha channel leaves `rgb(0,0,0)`. You can draw a white rectangle on the background of your canvas to workaround this issue.